# How to Run a php script every 3 hours in openshift

Tags: php, cron, openshift

I have a php script ( fetch.php )

I want that every 3 hours ( fetch.php ) automatically run.

I use OpenShift.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @ceejayoz There's no cron in openshift (or not that I'm aware of)

Comment: @wumm https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift

Comment: Please explain with an example for run every 3 hours fetch.php

Comment: @javad75 we're not a code authoring service. What have you tried? Putting in some effort is an important part of asking a question on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the cron cartridge and then follow the instructions that are laid out in this blog article: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift
to run a cron job.